# how do i change de default value of a model from a view function on django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my code

models.py

```
...
class Cobranza(models.Model):
    profesional = models.ForeignKey(Profesional)
    porcentaje_aporte = models.IntegerField(default=30)
...
```

what i  want to do is changing that default value of "porcentaje_aporte" to another number using a function in the views.py

Is that possible? if it is so, how can i do it? any alternative? 
I have looked for a solution in django docs and haven't got anything useful.
Also i tryed with the following function but it didn't worked

```
def cambiarAporte(request):
    nuevoAporte = request.POST['aporte']
    Cobranza.porcentaje_aporte.default = nuevoAporte;
```

basically i want this

```
porcentaje_aporte = models.IntegerField(default=30)
```

to become this

```
porcentaje_aporte = models.IntegerField(default=*new number*)
```

so any object of this class that i make in the future, get that new default value

Comment: Why are you not using a ModelForm?

Comment: a ModelForm is used when you want to create an object, what i want to do is change the class.

Comment: Using a ModelForm will do exactly what you want. You can pass the POST value to initial for the model and will be treated as default for the instance being created.

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc Exactly. Comment upvoted.

Comment: The approach is incorrect. You should store the value in the database or in a file locally and retrive it from there. If you want to change it via POST.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the default value of the model. Model layer is something that reflects your domain,  and domain just doesn't change on per request basis. Instead you most probably want to change the default value of the form widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by doing:

`Cobranza._meta.get_field('porcentaje_aporte').default = nuevoAporte`

This operation is dangerous as it will alter the field data for other requests.
What you should use is `ModelForm` with initial data.

This is how you should implemet this, hopefully I understood what you want:

Use a file or database to store the value in the view and retrive it here as the default for the field using the following method:

```
def get_default_percentaje():
    '''
    Read the value from where it is stored. File or database.
    '''

    try:
        fh = open('file_with_value.txt')
        data = int(fh.read().strip())
        fh.close()
    except:
        data = 30
    return data

class Cobranza(models.Model):
    profesional = models.ForeignKey(Profesional)
    porcentaje_aporte = models.IntegerField(default=get_default_porcentaje)
```

Comment: This operation will not affect other requests.

Comment: Changing Cobranza._meta.get_field('porcentaje_aporte').default = nuevoAporte won't affect other requests?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, it's affect)